# Route localhost port across home network?

Tags: networking

I have a program.

This program sends data through a websocket to `0.0.0.0:51246`.

I then have a HTML/JS script. This script monitors the websocket at `localhost:51246`

When both the program and the script are on the same computer, this works great.

However, I want to have the script on one computer, and have the program on another computer on my home network. Would would be the easiest way to route the data going across the port onto my network?

Answer (score 1):

If you got this `0.0.0.0:51246` from `netstat` output, then this means, that program listens on all IP addresses in this machine. Simply change the script in a way that instead of monitoring `localhost:51246` it monitors `<IP>:51246`. For example `192.168.0.11:51246`.